# How to format time data when importing txt file to access using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am importing txt file data into Access db using VBA using Transfer Text, however it read the first column as time and returns 09:11:00. How can I format the variables before or after importing the data? Thanks in advance!

```
data:

09:11,10

10:10,11    

    Sub Import()

    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "TheTable", "D:\T1.txt", True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Marc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before importing the data, I don't think there is a way for you to format the text since you import it all together at one go. If you need to, you may open up the file and read the text line by line to change its format.

After importing, if you need to use a formatted column of your table you can try CDATE and FORMAT function like below

```
CDATE(FORMAT(TheTable.field1, "dd:mm,yy"))
```

I assume your data is in Day:Month,Year format. If not, you can just change the format string accordingly.